# Is there a reason to connect tube reactors in series?

Tags: chemical-engineering

With CSTR (continuous stirred-tank reactor), it is in many cases benificial to connect multiple CSTR in series. I wonder if there is a purpose for tubular reactors to be connect in series as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may have thought, connecting tubular reactors in series could easily be replaced by a larger reactor.
But, sometimes, these reactors are sold in modules and you can add more or less modules according to demand.
I could use as an example series of adsorption columns or membrane separators.